# How to use the openni kinect plugin

Tags: gazebo, kinect, plugin, depth-image

I am trying to get a depth camera going in Gazebo Garden. I saw many tutorials like [this one](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_depth_camera&cat=connect_ros) which use the openni kinect plugin. (sdf code below)

Now when I implement a depth camera with this plugin in my sdf file I understandably get the error that that file is not found as I never downloaded it to my knowledge.

**TL;DR**:
Should the kinect plugin be in the gazebo download?
If not where can I download it?

I followed the links to this page: https://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera it says that this is unstable and references openni2 - don't know if this is compatible with my **Gazebo Garden** distribution. At this point I am very unsure whether I am not going down a wrong and too specific rabbit hole.

I appreciate any insights on this.

```
    <gazebo reference="${link_name}">
  <sensor name="${link_name}_camera" type="depth">
    <update_rate>20</update_rate>
    <camera>
      <horizontal_fov>1.047198</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>480</height>
        <format>R8G8B8</format>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>0.05</near>
        <far>3</far>
      </clip>
    </camera>
    <plugin name="${link_name}_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
      <baseline>0.2</baseline>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1.0</updateRate>
      <cameraName>${camera_name}_ir</cameraName>
      <imageTopicName>/${camera_name}/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>/${camera_name}/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <depthImageTopicName>/${camera_name}/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
      <depthImageInfoTopicName>/${camera_name}/depth/camera_info</depthImageInfoTopicName>
      <pointCloudTopicName>/${camera_name}/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
      <frameName>${frame_name}</frameName>
      <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
      <pointCloudCutoffMax>3.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
      <distortionK1>0.00000001</distortionK1>
      <distortionK2>0.00000001</distortionK2>
      <distortionK3>0.00000001</distortionK3>
      <distortionT1>0.00000001</distortionT1>
      <distortionT2>0.00000001</distortionT2>
      <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
      <Cx>0</Cx>
      <Cy>0</Cy>
      <focalLength>0</focalLength>
      <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing a dangerous combination of Gazebo-classic (and using `gazebo_ros_pkgs` with it given the use of `libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect`) and Gazebo Garden. This is probably not going to work.

Starting with plain Gazebo Garden: you can find a [depth camera tutorial](https://gazebosim.org/api/rendering/6/depth_camera.html) in gz-sensors and the [example code](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-rendering/tree/ign-rendering6/examples/simple_demo) to use with the tutorial. You also have a [depth camera SDF world](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/depth_camera_sensor.sdf) in gz-sim repository.

Going into ROS: if you are planning on using ROS 1 Noetic, please note that the version of Gazebo recommended is Citadel and Garden would not work. For the new Gazebo the replacement of `gazebo_ros_pkgs` is to use the `ros_gz` (previously known as `ros_ign`) bridge. There is an example of a depth camera working with [Gazebo Citadel + ROS Noetic running RViz and rqt_image](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/noetic/ros_ign_gazebo_demos#depth-camera).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Jose. That tutorial I found in the source code as well which helped me. I believe the link you sent still uses ignition packages if I'm not mistaken.
I believe it's just going to be trying to find the place in the source code where the depth image is created to see what parameters is not read in as I placed it to see where the discrepancy between the normal and depth camera comes from.